# get the path of a specific folder on a random PC

Tags: batch-file

I tried to generate a batch file to install my VBS-program on any Windows PC in the world which are all having a certain folder let us name it e.g. "tome" where this folder is part of a Program.

My VBS-Program has an EXE-file and three other folders (X1, Y2, Z3). The batch file should swap the EXE-file and also the three other folders (X1, Y2, Z3) to most certain folders on the target PC.

I want to do that with the xcopy procedure, but I'm not able to get the entire path from the folders on the target PCs where my files should be copied in. Beneath is my the attempt to get the path on the target PCs:

```
@echo off
for /d /r  "d:\folderX"  %%a in (*) do if "%%~nxa"=="tome" set "folderpath=%%~dpnxa"
  if defined folderpath (
     echo "%folderpath%"
)
pause
```

The problem is the different folderX names on the target PC, so the path couldn't generate. I was looking for a placeholder for folderX but didn't find it.

Comment: Since the `tome` directory is presumably part of an installed program, can't you check the registry to find the install location ?

Comment: Thx for ur reply. Ups don t wanna dive in a foreign Hkey reg

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use `/d /r` when you can utilize the simpler `dir` command:

```
@echo off
for /F %%i in ('dir /b /s /ad ^| findstr /ir "^tome$"') do echo %%~fi
```

You do not need `findstr` and can directly `dir` the directory, but I use `findstr` with regex to ensure you match only `tome` and not `tomes`, `"tome folder"`, `diatome`, etc.

If you explicitly require it to be only on a particular drive, simply `pushd D:\` or `cd /d D:\` prior to the for loop. You can also index each drive letter and run the search `for` loop on each drive i.e:

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=2*delims==" %%i in ('wmic logicaldisk get caption /value') do for /f "delims=" %%d in ("%%i") do (
  pushd %%d
  for /F %%i in ('dir /b /s /ad ^| findstr /ir "^tome$"') do echo %%~fi
  popd
)
Pause
```

Comment: Thx. Will give it a try tonight. Yes I m planning to do a if/else with the most common drive letters like C or E etc. What do u mean with „ index each drive letter and …“?

Comment: See the edit to my answer

Comment: Hello Gerhard, now it works in the way your batch find only the next folder of the drive.
But my "tome" folder is far away from any drive, there are many folders in between

Comment: thx again for watching my thread .... . I will explain it in an other way: In VBS there is the  wonderful "GetAbsolutePathName" - methode wich returns a complete and unambiguous path from a provided path specification.

e.g. the folder "tome" could be find in any order of a path on target machines. 
c:\ajj\jsh\sc\tome\gh\ghtt\
or
d:\sd\we\yx\uiu\tome
or
d:\tz\thome\der

That means I am looking for a batch finding the "tome" folder and returns the whole path

Comment: So all subdirectories included, updated answer by including `/s`

Comment: also think so today but only a blinking promt occurs ....